# Why bind a form to 2 variables when creating a form for nested resources in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

In my rails website I want to make a form with nested resources.
More specificly, I want to add a comment section to my blogposts.

The solution I found on several places is creating a form with the rails helper form_for and binding both the `@post` instance variable and the `@comment` instance variable to the form like this

```
<%= form_for[@post, @comment] do |f| %>
```

Now I was hoping that someone could explain me why it doesn't work to just bind it to `@comment`, even if you that comment has a foreign key to `@post`?
So in other words I still need to bind the form to both instance variables, even if I defined the following in my `show` action.

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
@comment = @post.comments.new
```

Rails is pretty smart, why isn't it able to figure out that `@comment` belongs to `@post`?

Comment: It should work.  If you do as you suggest, you can use `form_for @comment...` in your view and you'll get back comment attribute values which you can use to create a `comment` instance which is bound to the right `post`.

Comment: For me it doesn't work, I get an error `undefined method 'comments_path'` when I don't bind the form to @post

Comment: Yes as @eiriker mentions below, you would need a resource, but he makes an excellent point that this is not necessarily a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how `nested_resources` work. When you run `rake routes` you will find this route

```
POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)   comments#create
```

This means a value for `:post_id` key should be provided like defining `@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])`

When you try to give just `<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>`, Rails will trigger an error `No route matches comment_path` because it treats it as a ***non-nested resource***

Comment: I'm not sure who to give the accepted answer because all of you informed me well. Thank you for this

Answer (score 3):

`@post.comments.new` builds a new comment without saving it to the database. This non-persisted comment is then used to construct a form. Once you submit the form, the `create` action will build then save the comment only with the data submitted by the form. If `post_id` is not included in that data, Rails has no idea that the first comment had this value, since it wasn't persisted to the database.

As such, you can get around this, if desired, by adding the `post_id` field to the form:

```
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :post_id %>
```

This would obviously require a non-nested `resources :comments` in your routes.rb

However, I don't see a good reason to do this. Using the nested routes, e.g. the form in your question, guarantees that I have a valid `post_id` attached to the `@post` in question without having to add an extra field.

To put it another way, lets say I'm a spammer who saw the `post_id` field in the form. I could easily write code that would submit the form with my spam comment for all possible values of `post_id` between 1 and 1000000. When you used nested routes, not only is it more difficult to do this, but you can more easily check the validity of the `@post` object, whether a user can comment on it, etc. Obviously, this isn't a full-featured anti-spam system, but it can make spamming marginally more difficult while making it easier for you to perform the checks you need.

Comment: I'm not sure who to give the accepted answer because all of you informed me well. Thank you for this

Answer (score 1):

If you really didn't want to pass in both models to the form, you can manually set the action so that it will work. Probably something like this:

`<%= form_for @comment, url: post_comments_path(@comment.post) do |f| %>`

assuming `@comment.post` is defined.

But, I can't see the advantage to doing it this way.

As to 'why' Rails can't figure this out without the explicit inclusion of `post`, I would think it is because `comment` could possibly be associated with something other than a `post` and thus Rails cannot make any assumptions (e.g., you could allow comments to be associated with other comments).

Comment: I'm not sure who to give the accepted answer because all of you informed me well. Thank you for this